# Select multiple rows objects using Selenium in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I’m trying to write an automated scripts where I need to select multiple objects. Here is what I tried:

```
@browser.action.key_down(:left_shift).perform
post_elements[0].click
post_elements[2].click
@browser.action.key_up(:left_shift).perform
```

it doesn’t work for me. Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to structure your code like this:

```
@browser.action.key_down(:left_shift)
    .click(post_elements[0])
    .click(post_elements[2])
    .key_up(:left_shift).perform
```

Comment: @chenlayton On review, I realized I probably still had this wrong.  Give this a try.